# Role base access for LWC fields

Tags: admin

We are developing a application which is pure LWC based singe page application which contains about 100 + LWC components. Depending on roles is there a way to show or hide fields ?

Comment: I recommend you work through [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security) along with [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data).

Comment: Actually we are not using LDS in our LWC. All we are using is native lightning web component controls. Lets say i am having a LWC component which contains two lightning input and one lightning checkbox . For one role I need to show only text box and for other role i need to show only check box. Without coding is there a way we can achieve this?